# How to add PKCE to accessCode flow in Swashbuckle Swagger 5.6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, pkce

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.6.0 to use Swagger on my .Net Framework 4.8 WebAPI. I need it to authenticate against an updated Identity Server (v6) which requires PKCE when using a browser to sign in. I've found plenty of examples on how to eg set usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant to true but I cannot find any similar options anywhere in the 5.6.0 configuration options. How do I tell Swashbuckle/Swagger to use PKCE?